# XAML files of referenced library not copied over during build

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Windows Store apps do no longer compile the xaml files into the assembly, but copies them over to the debug/release folder (Build Action: Page). To be able to reference the xaml files, eg. in a ResourceDictionary, you have to use the ms-appx syntax:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///{assemblyname}/{folder}/{xamlfile}.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

When referencing another assembly with XAML files, you should have a folder with the same name as the assembly:

```
/referencefolder/some.assembly.dll
/referencefolder/some.assembly/subfolder/xamlfile
```

I've used this before without problem in a few projects, however in my last project I can't get this to work. For some odd reason, the xaml files from the referenced assembly doesn't get copied over to the debug/release folders. Since files are not copied over, it's quite obvious that I'm getting errors on my resource dictionary merging.

After adding the Callisto nuget package (also contains a Themes.xaml file), 2 out of 3 personal assembly folders got copied over. Deleting the debug folder and rebuilding brings me back to step 1: no files being copied over (not even the one from Callisto).

Since it's just a reference to local available assemblies, I have no clue where it goes wrong.

Comment: good to compare the 'build action' and 'custom tool' advanced properties for the xaml files -- in a project that works, and in a project that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like things went wrong because of different nuget package versions between this project and some of the referenced projects.

Another hint: if you offload everything to other assemblies and therefor have no xaml files (not even the common styles that gets added on project creation) in your Windows Store client app, I've seen similar issues show up. Adding an empty dummy page is enough to get things going again.

Answer (score 1):

There's been a bug with project reference in WinRT. Basically, if you add a reference via a DLL the output folder hierarchy is wrong for this project.
If you add the whole project to your solution, this bug should not occur.

I think it has been fixed in the Visual Studio 2012 **Update 2** which released last week.

Is your visual studio up to date ?

If it is, and it is callisto you want to use, just don't use the nuget package, and download the full project sources, then add this project to your solution. That should work.

Comment: It works correctly, but you have to provide a folder named as the assembly yourself and place XAML files in there.

Comment: I know it does, but you should not have to create the folder yourself. Since you referenced a project, the output folder tree should be correctly created by visual studio. As I said, I think it has been fixed in the Update 2 of visual studio

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but what happens if you "Cope Local" on the reference to that project ?

Comment: Copy Local is true for all referenced assemblies (in both working and failing project).